# display only one card in recycler view at a time

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I created a recyclerView for my app with cards inside it. When I swipe on the recyclerView half of the next card is displayed [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z9rTE.jpg) . I wanted that if I swipe the next card id fully visible [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rcl4k.jpg) can someone help me in achieving this effect.

Comment: I think maybe you should look into using a ViewPager instead of a recycler view for this purpose.

Comment: viewPager2 would be fine in this case

Comment: please share a sample code i think here is xml issue